# Is it possible to subscribe to a newsletter without first having to register?

Tags: emails

I am using the [Simplenews](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews) module, but from what I've been able to conclude, is not possible to subscribe to a newsletter without first having to register.  Is that correct?

Is there a different newsletter module which will enable me to do this: offer a newsletter subscription to users without having to first become a registered user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supposed to be possible, but the anonymous user is still required to confirm their email address. Check this [issue](http://drupal.org/node/1182402) in the Simplenews issue queue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You do not need to register to subscribe to a simple news list. It is the default way to use the module.